# Cannot write to Windows to Go root directory

Tags: windows, file-permissions, windows-to-go

I have a Windows to Go drive that I'd also like to use as a normal flash drive.

However, I can't move files to the root directory, or copy files there. Attempting to do so produces this error:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from creating the file. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for helm with this problem.
>
> Error 0x80070522: A required privilege is not held by the client.

Looking around for a solution seems to turn up fixes that apply for a locked-up `C:` drive, but this drive isn't `C:`, and turning off my own personal UAC doesn't sound portable.

*Note:*

Giving `Everyone` `Full Control` in the security settings does not seem to help.

> E: NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(S,AD)
>
> NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
>
> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CF)(F)
>
> BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
>
> Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)
>
> BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
>
> Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level :(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)

Creating a file from an administrator PowerShell session works fine.

Comment: Can you add the result of `icacls X:` to your question, where X is your drive letter? Have you tried an elevated command prompt?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf updated with requested information.

Comment: the permission seem OK, and even if they weren't you should get an `Access Denied` (0x5) not a 0x80070522. Can you create a directory in the root as normal or elevated user?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I can create a directory as a normal user no problem.

Comment: I would ignore that error and store all my files in directories under the root. Storing files on the root level is never a great idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on a more recent build (10586), and the problem seems fixed. :)

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem on build 17763, so not sure this was ever fixed. You may have gotten lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling UAC? Same thing happened on my Workstation, and now it is working great.

- Start/Run/`secpol.msc`
- Local Policies
- Security Options
- User Account Control: Run all admins in admin approval mode and Right Click
- Click properties
- Check disabled
- Reboot Computer/PC.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, it didn't help.